# Xamarin.Android create back button in toolbar with text of previous view

Tags: android, xamarin.android

So I want to create a back button on every View I open in my Xamarin Android app. To explain better here is the screenshots, that will help me explain my problem:

Lets assume this is my first view when I open app:

[image]

When I click three dots popup menu opens. And for example I select Profile item.

Then this view opens:

[image]

Now as you can see at the top I have back button, but the text near the button is hardcoded... How can I make it show me previous view name? In this case it should be "List".

Moreover, I don't know how to implement back button to get back, and I was looking for any kind of tutorial or example, but couldn't find any... could someone please help me?

**UPDATE 1**

I am using MvvmCross in my application there are some places where I navigate between activities and some places where I navigate between fragments, I thinking about unifying everything and make navigation only between fragments...

For now I didn't made any implementation of back button, I need some help with that

Comment: Are you using MvvmCross? How is your design? Did you navigate between activities or fragments? And how did you perform "go back"? Could you please show some code?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I updated my question